# jQuery slide vertical images

Tags: jquery

I hope someone can help me with the following problem.

I have a vertical scrollbar on my website which shows 5 images and will scroll 5 images further or back, depeding on where you clicked.

The jQuery code looks like this.

```
$(".productSlide .scrollable").scrollable();
$(".productSlide .scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });
```

I am new to jQuery and what I can achieve ist the following

```
<div class="scrollBlock">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        include 'example1.php';
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollBlock">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        include ' example1.php';
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollBlock">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        include ' example1.php';
    ?>
</div>
```

In example1.php there is an image which will be showed 5 times. And everytime you click you’ll see the same div again with the same 5 pics. I can’t figure this one out without the "scrollBlock" div. How can I use more pictures in just one block – and it’s still scrolling 5 images?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an horizontal scroll:

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable();
```

If you want vertical scroll:

```
$(".productSlide .scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });
```

Use both block everyting, unfortunately don't create a diagonal scroll :D

Solution:
comment/erase first ".scrollable" call